# JDBC: Call Oracle function like a procedure

Tags: oracle, jdbc, plsql

I use an Oracle procedure and I batch it.

```
CallableStatement st = con.prepareCall ("{call MyProc (123)}");
...
st.addBatch ();
```

Now the procedure was converted into a function. Therefore batching is not longer working and ignoring the return-value does not work too.
If I do not set the "? =" the function is not found.

```
CallableStatement st = con.prepareCall ("{? = call MyFunc (123)}");
```

But without batching it takes too long to run all the calls. I have to do many of them.

So is there a way I can ignore the return-value on the JDBC level without touching the function? I want my batching back.

Answer (score 2):

You may of course used the Oracle syntax and ignore the function value in the PL/SQL Block.

Something like this

```
con.prepareCall("""
declare
 v_ignore number;
begin
  v_ignore := MyFunc (?);
end;""")
```

Answer (score 0):

for oracle db it will be like:

```
private Long getResultOfFunction(final long param1) {

    CallableStatementCallback<Long> action = new CallableStatementCallback<Long>() {
        public Long doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs)
                throws SQLException, DataAccessException {

            cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.NUMERIC);
            cs.setLong(2, param1);

            cs.executeQuery();

            return cs.getLong(1);
        }
    };

    return getJdbcTemplate().execute("{call ? := package_name.function_name (?)}", action);
}
```

Comment: Please reread the question. The question is about how to call a function in batched mode. Using the SQL92 syntaxt returns `java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed: Stored procedure with out or inout parameters cannot be batched`